# Linear isomorphism of quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Need some help.

Let $M,N$ subspaces of L. Prove that the following map is a linear isomorphism.

$$\phi:\frac{M+N}{N}\longrightarrow\frac{M}{M\cap N}$$
Defined by $$\phi(m+n+N)=m+M\cap N$$

I'm stucked

Comment: I try do $\phi(m+n+N)=0+M\cap N$. But, i think that dont implies m=0 and n=0

Comment: If $\phi(m+n+N)=0+M\cap N$, then $m\in M\cap N$, and thus $m+n\in N$.

Comment: I would define the map in the opposite direction. That's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m+M\cap N=m'+M\cap N$, then $m-m'\in M\cap N$ so $m-m'\in N$ ($m'+N=m+N$) and $\phi$ is injective. The map is also surjective since $\phi(m+N)=m+M\cap N$.

Comment: If $m+X=0+X$ so $m\in X$?

Comment: Yes, $m+X=\{m+x\mid x\in X\}$, so if $m+X=0+X$ then $m\in X$.

Comment: @MatheusNunes No problem!